# URI exception every time

Tags: c#

I'm getting a url from a http request but I get an exception

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

when the url is valid for example I get this exception with

```
http://thepiratebay.se/user/paulo_c2010/
```

Here is the code I am using :

```
string[] dataParts = data.Split(' ');
string method = dataParts[0];
Console.WriteLine(dataParts[1]);
Uri uri = new Uri(dataParts[1]);
string host = StringUtils.ReplaceFirst(uri.Host, "www.", "");
```

Comment: What exactly is in `dataParts[1]`?

Comment: I am splitting a http request so data parts would be the url of the website

Comment: I am writing a proxy so it is the full url ;)

Comment: So if it is URL, it should work. Does it make sense to ask question if you do not want to provide helpfull details?

Comment: have you tried to debug your code? try and see what dataParts[1] contains prior to creating a Uri from it...

Comment: That's why I have this line `Console.WriteLine(dataParts[1]);`

Comment: I have put this peace of your code `Uri uri = new Uri("http://thepiratebay.se/user/paulo_c2010/")` and its working fine. It means there is something else in `dataPats[1]` which isn't displaying. You may debug it instead of displaying.

Comment: Fixed it did not have http:// ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(dataParts[1], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```